agent.getNearestAgentByRoute() using GIS
I am using GIS. In my model I want to send ambulances (my resources) to the location of some emergencies call which arise somewhere random in the map.
I use the function emergency.getNearestAgentByRoute(ambulance_population) to send the nearest ambulance to the emergency but the output does not always coincide with the nearest one: how anyLogic compute the routing-distance between points?

As per the help:

It uses the route-provider you specify. So it is a black-box unless you have your own routing
